# When Installing Ubuntu from bootable USB, the computer boots to USB but Ubuntu installer does not show up

Tags: dual-boot, usb

I was dual booting Ubuntu 18 lts but when I booted from USB, the computer showed up a warning (See in the picture) and then it went to grub command line. Any fix to this?.

My PC is HP Elite 8300, windows 10 pro installed.

Also I'm totally new to Ubuntu :)

[Warning Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Epy9g.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

did dual booting setup fail?

- if yes you might make the bootable flash in a wong way or the way you make the flash is the problem ı suggest you to use [Unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) or [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/)
- while making the bootable flash and check if you are using iso for
  the right system, for example, _64 or _32
- also, it might because of the secure boot or fast boot is enabled try
  to close them from booting screen of your laptop .

Comment: i used rufus to make the bootable usb

Comment: Is used GPT scheme in Rufus, should i use MBR?

Comment: yes also you can check here that you should use MBR (link)[https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#3-usb-selection]

Comment: i think that's the problem

Comment: i should choose MBR option in rufus

Comment: will update in a moment

Comment: yes you should use MBR and even if that still doesnt work use UNetbootin that i provided the link

Comment: alright, thank you so much